# Does a session variable stay in memory in php

Tags: php, session-variables

If I store contents of a text file in a session variable in php, will it stay in memory for the period of that session?

I have a small project where I need to perform searches in that specific text file which is just over 1mb. I'm thinking of using a session variable if it stays in memory, so that I don't have to read this file again and again.

Comment: Any amount of data can be stored there because the session is kept on the server side.

The only limitation is sessionId length, which shouldn't exceed ~4000 bytes - this limitation is implied by HTTP header length limitation to 4Kb since sessionId may be stored in the cookie or encoded in URL (using "URL rewriting") and the cookie specification says the size of cookie as well as HTTP request (e.g. GET /document.html ) cannot be longer then 4kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sessions will be stored default in files (e.g. in /tmp). Of course, you can use the memory with for example memcached. It's also possible to use a database for sessions.

But, if you have enough memory, store your sessions in memory (very fast). Memcached is a great distributed memory object caching system. See http://memcached.org for more information.

And here about the memcached extension for php: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Answer (score 1):

It will be stored using a file in the server. You can see session files in the path defined by [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php). Depending on the file system, the file could stay in memory depending on usage, but basically is a file.

I forgot to mention that the info was obtained mainly from here: [Where and How is data stored in a session?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/where-and-how-is-data-stored-in-a-session)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will stay in memory for the life of the session. Your 1mb is far from the max capacity it can hold (default I think is 128MB).
However, test both ways if it would be more efficient to just read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

session is stored either in file or in database, it does not consume PHP memory(server memory).